# How do you replace values chosen with a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I'm *very* new at javascript and am attempting to create a slider scale that outputs a phrase instead of a value. The coding looks like this so far. I used the [slider code from jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) as a base to learn.

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
   value:1,
   min: 1,
   max: 7,
   step: 1,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
   }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
 } );
```

I was thinking of adding an if / else statement, but I don't know how to implement it. I want each number to have a separate phrase attached to it. Is there a way to replace the output value (ex. 1, 2, 3, etc) with a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add cases up to your max number for the slider..

```js
var determineWord = function(value) {
  var word = "";
  console.log(value);
  switch (value) {

    case 1:
      word = "test";
      break;

    case 2:
      word = "test2";
      break;
  }
  console.log(word);
  return word;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(determineWord(ui.value));
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="amount"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to display only one result? Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/4/) of what I've been working on. I'd like to replace the wavelength:X with wavelength:word. Thank you so much for replying so fast!!

Comment: You're welcome. Thought about it more last night, and if you wanted to make it even simplier, you could use an array with the words, and just get the key value using the number as the index: https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/13/